# How to show .srt/subtitle file in MPmovieviewController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, video-player, srt

I am working on MPMovieViewController player for showing video in my app but need to show .Srt as well

I have used below code

```
    if(self.livePlayer)
    {
        [self.livePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.livePlayer stop];
        self.livePlayer=nil;
    }
    self.livePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:self.livePlayer.view];
    self.livePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 64.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 10.0, viwVideo.frame.size.height - 10.0);
    self.livePlayer.view.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.livePlayer.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:true];

    self.livePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    self.livePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    self.livePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    frame = self.livePlayer.view.frame;
```